# in dojo, not able to send multiple files using FileInput and iFrame

Tags: iframe, dojo, multipart, file-io

I am sending a multipart request using FileInput and iframe

```
var _newForm;
        if(dojo.isIE < 9 || (dojo.isIE && dojo.isQuirks)){
            // just to reiterate, IE is a steaming pile of code.
            _newForm = document.createElement('<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">');
            _newForm.encoding = "multipart/form-data";

        }else{
            // this is how all other sane browsers do it
            _newForm = document.createElement('form');
            _newForm.setAttribute("enctype","multipart/form-data");
        }
        _newForm.appendChild(foo.fileInput);
        console.log("FP is "+foo.fileInput);
        dojo.body().appendChild(_newForm);

        var o = dojo.io.iframe.send({
            url: foo.url,
            form: _newForm,
            load: uploadComplete,
            error: onBeforeSend
        });
```

I am facing issue that, I can send only one successful request. For second I need to refresh the page. Please let me know, what I need to do for sending multiple files.

Answer (score 0):

I am using dojo 1.6 and had a very similar problem that I resolved with the following method:

```
dojo.io.iframe._currentDfd = null; //insert this line
dojo.io.iframe.send
({...
```

*verified in Chrome Version 25.0.1364.152 m

Source: http://mail.dojotoolkit.org/pipermail/dojo-interest/2012-May/066109.html